# What are the main changes in CAP437 rev 9 from a Helideck Monitoring perspective?

Tags: helicopter, helipad

[CAP437 rev 9](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP437%20Standards%20for%20offshore%20helicopter%20landing%20areas%20E9.pdf) was first published Edition 9 February 2023. In particular, what should a Heliops operator conducting operations on a "moving" helideck be made aware of. What training would an operator require assuming that the standard is applicable and enforced?

Comment: Are you asking for a hobby simulation, school, or for work?

Comment: this is from a professional standpoint.